# Getting random increment while trying to count no of uppercase letters in C

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to find the no of lower and uppercase characters from a input.

here's my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char cAFirst[25];
    int k = 0,uc =0 ,lc =0 ;

    fgets(cAFirst,25,stdin);
    // printf("out: %d \n",k);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      k = (int)cAFirst[i];
      if ((k <= 90) && (k >= 65)) {
        uc++;
      }
      if ((k >= 97) && (k <= 122)) {
        lc++;
      }
    }

    printf("Uppercase Letters=%i \nLowercase Letters=%i \n",uc,lc );
    return 0;
}
```

lowercase (`lc`) is ok, but value of `uc` is randomly incremented.

I have already tried changing formatting of printf and it sometimes work, but problem is i have to submit this code with same formatting given above.

Comment: Try `for (size_t i = 0; i < 25; i++)` --> `for (size_t i = 0; cAFirst[i]; i++)`

Comment: Also change the conditions like `if ((k <= 'Z') && (k >= 'A'))`, to be more readable.

Comment: `if ((k <= 90) && (k >= 65))` ==> `if (isupper(k))` and `if ((k >= 97) && (k <= 122))` ==> `if (islower(k))`.

Comment: Rather than using the numeric values for the characters you can instead use the character itself in a single quote. So `if ((k <= 90) && (k >= 65)) {` can also be written `if ((k <= 'Z') && (k >= 'A')) {` and doing this makes the code more understandable as to what you are doing. Also you need to process only the number of characters actually entered and not the entire array. So if the number of characters entered is only 2 then you need to only do the loop two times. So rather than doing the entire 25 characters you need to do to the end of the string as in `strlen(cAFirst)`.

Comment: @RichardChambers Ok, thanks for the tip, so i am receiving wrong numbers because of random crap in memory maybe.

Comment: @chux i don't know how that can work as `cAFirst` is an char array.

Comment: @mch neat these functions are in string header file right

Comment: @X2tf I suppose [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54183805/getting-random-increment-while-trying-to-count-no-of-uppercase-letters-in-c?noredirect=1#comment95196803_54183805) ,means you are not going to try [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54183805/getting-random-increment-while-trying-to-count-no-of-uppercase-letters-in-c?noredirect=1#comment95196074_54183805).  Your call.

Comment: `for (size_t i = 0; i < 25; i++) { if (cAFirst[i] == 0) fprintf(stderr, "Found NUL character ... continuing ...\n");`

Comment: @X2tf If only `"xyz\n"` was entered, do you still want code to iterate 25 times?

Comment: @chux dearly noted, thx for the heads up i was liitle confused how the value of an char array could be used as a statement but ofc a null bye can serve as false

Comment: @X2tf Detail: `cAFirst[i]` is not the value of a _char array_.   `cAFirst[i]` is the  value of a single array element, which is of type `char`.  `cAFirst` is an array.

Comment: @chux i know that, the thing that confuse me was how `for (..;cAFirst[i];..)` this could be succeed  in iterating. how will the loop break. When there is no chars left.

Comment: @chux i know that, the thing that confuse me was how `for (..;cAFirst[i];..)` this could be succeed  in iterating. how will the loop break. When there is no chars left.

Comment: @X2tf Yes, `for (..;cAFirst[i];..)` will stop iterating when `cAFirst[i]` becomes zero - IOWs, when `i` indexes the _null character_ - the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering this snippet from OP's posted code:

```
char cAFirst[25];          // <- Uninitialized, the contents are indeterminated
// ...
fgets(cAFirst,25,stdin);   // <- We don't know if it succeeded or not
// ...
for (size_t i = 0; i < 25; i++) { 
    // ...         ^^^^^^
}
```

It copies **up to 24** chars from `stdin` to the array (including the newline, if present), also adding the null-terminator (if no stream error occurred), but when the loop is executed, it goes over **all the 25** char of the array, even if the inputted string is shorter, taking into account chars with indeterminate value.

To avoid this, we just have to test only the characters which were actually read from the input stream, by counting them or using the null-terminator as a sentinel.

We could intialize the array (to zero) and also avoid the use of repeated magic numbers, which is error prone.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// I'd use a bigger value, like 256, but OP's use case is not specified.
enum {
    BUF_SIZE = 25   
};

int main(void)
{
    // All the elements of the array are set to zero, not only the first.
    char buf[BUF_SIZE] = {'\0'};
    // ...
```

Now, even if all the chars in the array are tested in the previous loop, there won't be spurious values and the statistics will be consistent. This is not a real solution, though, and while it is commonly suggested to initialize all the variables before their use, in this case it is not necessary.

As noted by [chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux), the return value of functions like `fgets` should be checked, to verify that the operation has succeeded and that our variables are in a valid state.

```
    if ( fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, stdin) == NULL ) {
        if (feof(stdin)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Abnormal end of input.\n");
            // The contents of the array are not altered
        } 
        if (ferror(stdin)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "A stream error occurred.\n");
            // The contents of the array are indeterminated, maybe not even null-terminated
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
```

The key point is to be sure that, after this call, the array is null-terminated. Even a check like the following could be enough:

```
    if ( fgets(buf, BUF_SIZE, stdin) == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred while reading from stdin.\n");
        buf[0] = '\0';
        // Continues the program despite the error, but with a valid (empty) string
    }
```

It's worth remembering that any further characters besides the ones read, remain in the input stream.

Now that we have a valid (null-terminated) array, we can loop through it:

```
    int uc = 0, lc = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; buf[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    // which can also be written as 'for (size_t i = 0; buf[i]; i++) {'
    // It's also more readable without magic numbers:
        if ( 'A' <= buf[i]  &&  buf[i] <= 'Z' ) {  
            uc++;
        }
        else if ( 'a' <= buf[i]  &&  buf[i] <= 'z' ) {
            lc++;
        }
    }
    printf("Uppercase Letters = %i\nLowercase Letters = %i\n", uc, lc);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The previous snippet may be generalized from ASCII codes using functions like `isupper` and `islower` defined in header `<ctype.h>`. Also, the actual length of the string can be used to limit the for-loop:

```
    // Length of the maximum initial segment of the array, that consists of
    // only the characters not equal to a newline or null character
    size_t length = strcspn(buf, "\n");

    int uc = 0, lc = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        unsigned char k = buf[i];
        if ( isupper(k) ) {
            uc++;
        }
        else if ( islower(k) ) {
            lc++;
        }
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: `char cAFirst[25] = {};` ==> `char cAFirst[25] = {0};` empty initialization list is invalid C (may be valid is some language I don't know).

Comment: This is a bit of a technical detail but the new line character, `'\n'` is not a text character so it will not be counted regardless.

Comment: I'm curious what happens if more than 25 characters are entered by the user.

Comment: Even though buffer initialization may meet various blanket coding styles as with `char cAFirst[25] = {'\0'};` it is insufficient and unnecessary.  Instead, check the return value from `fgets()`.  Should `fgets()` return `NULL` due to an input error, that prior initialization provides no benefit as `cAFirst` is now indeterminate.

Comment: @RichardChambers [Re: if more than 25 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54183805/getting-random-increment-while-trying-to-count-no-of-uppercase-letters-in-c#comment95199404_54184579) If more than 24 characters are entered (`'\n'` is a character), they remain in `stdin` for later.

Comment: @chux yes the remaining characters remain however there is only the single `fgets()` nor is there a new line in the first read.

Comment: @RichardChambers "nor is there a new line in the first read." is unclear. Why is that of concern?  Is the functionality of `strcspn(cAFirst, "\n")` unclear?

Comment: @chux That came unchanged from OP's code, my bad. I'll keep the initialization, but I agree it's not necessary, given the other checks.

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes `'\n'` will not be counted, but I mentioned it while thinking about the determination of the length of the string, not about the lower/upper case count. It may be worded better.

Comment: When I read the OP's posting, it sounded like a beginning programming class assignment and the approach that I would have taken would have been the simplest procedure of (1) read in the string, (2) find the length of the string, (3) loop over the string with an `if` statement to count either lower case or upper case. Since it appears to be a beginning program class assignment, it would seem that a minimum of C library functions should be used in order to emphasize the underlying technical details which are hidden by using the library such as what constitutes a lower case character.

Comment: @RichardChambers Thanks for your inputs. Please consider editing this post, any suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Rather then always iterate 25 times, iterate until the end of input is detected.

```
// for (size_t i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
for (size_t i = 0; cAFirst[i]; i++) {  // detect null character.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first use a way to iterate your string only once maybe a `while` loop and try to read not just what you need but also what there could be which should not be counted. What happens if there is `\t` or `\n` Do you need them to count too?

Here is an approach which can help you to understand that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char string[] = "AbcDEfgHiJKlmnOPqrstUVWxyZ\n§$%$§";
    int uc, lc, i, others;
    uc = lc = i = others = 0;

    while ( string[i] )
    {
        if ( string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z'  )
        {
            uc++;
        }else if ( string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z' ){
            lc++;
        }else{
            others++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if ( i == ( lc + uc + others ) )
    {
        printf( "OK\n\n" );
        printf("Uppercase Letters = %i \nLowercase Letters = %i \nOthers = %d \n", uc, lc, others );
        printf("Total = %d\n", i );
    }else
    {
        printf("Something went Wrong.\n\n");
    }
}
```

Your `if/else` statements could be easy replaced by the functions `isupper( string[i] )` and `islower( string[i] )` which are found in `ctype.h`

```
if ( isupper( string[i] ) )
{
    uc++;
}else if ( islower( string[i] ) )
{
    lc++;
}else{
    others++;
}
```